# SSIS - COZYROCK Zip Task Editor differente files

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008, cozyroc

I need some help.

I'm trying to zip 3 files, as I you can see in the image

[image]

But i only want to zip the two .pdf files (the name is dynamic) and the xml file.
I want to ignore the others .zip files that exist in that folder.

Anyone knows? Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: 1. Using fileinfo.Extension != ".zip"
2. Only select file which are doesn't have extension as .zip
3. Then zip all the other files

Comment: But where I use that "fileinfo.Extension != ".zip""?